Ability to have Configurable Product have same SKU as child?
Currently as it looks, when creating a Configurable product, it needs its own SKU, and then the SKUs of its children all different;
Configurable SKU: XX-SHIRT
Child 1:          XX-SHIRT-BLACK
Child 2:          XX-SHIRT-RED

The issue I run into with this, is I would like the Configurable SKU to default to Black, and be seen/searched for in the same manner. Essentially to where I would like the 1st Child XX-SHIRT-BLACK act as the main product (similar to finding as a simple product) but also have the 2nd Child be visible/interchangeable with the 1st Child (ideally via something like visual swatch), to where it works something like;
Configurable SKU: XX-SHIRT-BLACK
Child 1:          XX-SHIRT-BLACK
Child 2:          XX-SHIRT-RED

But as how the Configurable Product works, it will create that product, and 2 separate child SKUs (that are set to Not Visible Individually) .. so I am not hopeful but figured I'd try. Is there any way to accomplish what I am looking for in the second example?
